# How to select field name in datatable according to condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select column name in datatable according to condition. For example according to a condition in which a field name must contain substring as a
`"price"`.

DataTable is below

`id | name place | car_price | bike_price`

Comment: what do you want to achieve? show some code.

Comment: why don't you use like operator

Comment: i want to get selected field name car_price and  bike_price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'db_name' 
  and table_name = 'table_name' 
  and column_name like '%price%';
```

This lists all the field_name with "price" as substring in the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to conditinally select either car_price or bike_price for any given record in the resultset of a query on the talble,
you can use a [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement, like this:

```
SELECT name, 
    CASE 
      WHEN name LIKE '%car%' THEN car_price -- your condition here
      ELSE bike_price 
    END AS price 
FROM dataTable
```